# Terraform - Validating a passed list of strings against a local list of strings

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

I'm working on creating an Azure Event Grid Terraform module, and there's only a specified list of event types that are approved to be used. An Azure Policy will also be deployed to also do the same functionality from a ClickOps perspective as well (as to serve as a secondary filter).

Below are the relevant snippets of code:

locals.tf

```
local {
    event_types = [
        "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated",
        "Microsoft.Storage.BlobDeleted",
        "Microsoft.Storage.BlobRenamed",
        "Microsoft.Web.AppUpdated"
    ]
}
```

variables.tf (Default is an example of customer input)

```
variable "included_event_types" {
    type = list(string)
    default = ["Microsoft.Storage.BlobDeleted",
               "Microsoft.Storage.BlobRenamed",
               "Microsoft.Storage.DirectoryRenamed"
    ]
}
```

My question is, how do I build the validation rule so it will check it each item in the passed variables list against the locals list to see if all exists? I initially had a solution that gave a *missing item separator* error at the for keyword:

```
variable "included_event_types" {
    type = list(string)
    default = []

    validation {
        condition = all([contains(lower(local.event_types), lower(s)) for s in var.included_event_types])
        error_message = "Error"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A variable validation rule must be self-contained and not refer to anything else in the module, so you can't refer to `local.event_types` here but you can inline its value into the expression, like this:

```
variable "included_event_types" {
  type = list(string)
  default = []

  validation {
    condition = alltrue([
      for s in var.included_event_types :
      contains(
        [
          "microsoft.storage.blobcreated",
          "microsoft.storage.blobdeleted",
          "microsoft.storage.blobrenamed",
          "microsoft.web.appupdated",
        ],
        lower(s),
      )
    ])
    error_message = "<helpful error message>"
  }
}
```